# Using CSS filter to increase Saturation on webpage and Streaming video container

Tags: css, video-streaming, saturation-arithmetic

I'm using a super simple CSS filter to increase Saturation on a webpage (and it's video's) via Stylus extension,

html {
filter: Saturation (125%)
}

it works on the webpage without issue but then the embedded video's are blacked out with sound ....

I'm obviously a "noob" in coding and just saw a phew tutorials, any help/suggetions would be lovely

ty.